# Trying to use setTypeface in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-typeface

```
 public class HelpSettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    Typeface champagneRegularFont;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial, container, false);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Help");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getContext(), "Candy.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        actionBar.setTitle(s);

        champagneRegularFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf");

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        mPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getContext());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
            collection.addView(layout);

            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ModelObject.values().length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];

            return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
        }

    }

    public enum ModelObject {

        FIRST(R.string.blue, R.layout.tutorial_1),
        SECOND(R.string.red, R.layout.tutorial_2),
        THIRD(R.string.green, R.layout.tutorial_3);

        private int mTitleResId;
        private int mLayoutResId;

        ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
            mTitleResId = titleResId;
            mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
        }

        public int getTitleResId() {
            return mTitleResId;
        }

        public int getLayoutResId() {
            return mLayoutResId;
        }

    }

}
```

I am using a `ViewPager` so the user can scroll through 3 different layouts. I am trying to set a custom typeface to some `TextView`s and `Button`s. Does anyone know where I instantiate the objects and be able to set the custom typeface via `setTypeface(champagneRegularFont)`?

Edit: <s>Also, would I add `onClickListeners` in the same place?</s>

No longer need to know how to implement `onClickListeners` as I have replaced it with an `onClick` method in the xml file, and declared the method in my activity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating the layout as,

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)   
inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
```

Now set the typeFace you initialized on your **onCreateView()** as follows,

```
TextView textView=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTypeface(champagneRegularFont);
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it causes the app to crash. The error says I am trying to invoke the method on a null object reference.

Comment: Actually, this solution worked, however, I needed to surround `textView.setTypeface(champagneRegularFont);` with `if (textView != null)` .